Question About Comparative Statics and Optimization
Let me try to describe my question first. By solving the following maximization problem
$$
\max_{t_P} U_{B_i}(t_P) = (1-t_P)y_{B_i} + V_{B_i}(g),
$$
where $V_{B_i}$ is a function of $g$ and $g=t_P\cdot\overline{y}$ (so one may write $V_{B_i}(g)=V_{B_i}(t_P\cdot\overline{y})$), we obtained the first order condition
$$
\frac{\partial U_{B_i}}{\partial t_P} = -y_{B_i} + V'_{B_i}(t^*_P\overline{y})\cdot\overline{y}=0 \implies V'_{B_i}(t^*_P)=\frac{y_{B_i}}{\overline{y}}.
$$
Note that $y_{B_i}$ is defined by $y_{B_i}=\frac{\phi k}{\pi(1-\beta)}$. Now define a function $R_i$ by
$$
R_i = p_B\left(\frac{(t^*_A-t^*_P)\phi k}{\pi(1-\beta)}+V_{B_i}(t^*_P\overline{y})\right)-c_{B_i}.
$$
I want to see how changes in $\phi$ will affect changes in $R_i$. So I take partial derivative of $R_i$ with respect to $\phi$, right? But I got a bit confused with doing the partial differentiation.
I am not sure whether I should consider the effect of a change in $\phi$ on $t^*_P$. You see, the $t^*_P$ is the optimizer of the maximization problem, where $y_{B_i}$ is a variable that depends on $\phi$. So a change in $\phi$ should changes the $t^*_P$, and thus should changes $V_{B_i}(t^*_P\overline{y})$, right? So when calculate $\frac{\partial R_i}{\partial\phi}$, shouldn't I wrote
$$
\frac{\partial R_i}{\partial\phi} = \frac{\partial p_B}{\partial\phi}\left(\frac{(t^*_A-t^*_P)\phi k}{\pi(1-\beta)}+V_{B_i}(t^*_P\overline{y})\right) + p_B\cdot\left(\frac{k(t^*_A-t^*_P)}{\pi(1-\beta)}+V'_{B_i}(t^*_P\overline{y})\cdot\overline{y}\frac{\partial t^*_P}{\partial\phi}\right)?
$$
But the book that I am reading wrote instead
$$
\frac{\partial R_i}{\partial\phi} = \frac{\partial p_B}{\partial\phi}\left(\frac{(t^*_A-t^*_P)\phi k}{\pi(1-\beta)}+V_{B_i}(t^*_P\overline{y})\right) + p_B\cdot\left(\frac{k(t^*_A-t^*_P)}{\pi(1-\beta)}\right).
$$
Am I wrong or is the book wrong? Or is the term $V'_{B_i}(t^*_P\overline{y})\cdot\overline{y}\frac{\partial t^*_P}{\partial\phi}=0$ (but I failed to see this though)? Could someone please help me out? Thanks a lot in advance!
(I suspect it might involve some results from optimization such as the Envelope Theorem, but I am not sure.)

I have tried to rephrase the model so that I don't have to type the whole model out which is quite complicated. But if you still have trouble understanding it, please comment below. I will try my best to clarify it!

Reference$\quad$ Chapter 4 Section 4.4 in Inequality and Democratization by Angel and Samuels.

The book is correct, and this is indeed implied by the envelope theorem. To see why, note that there is a calculation mistake in your partial differentiation:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial R_i}{\partial\phi} &= \frac{\partial p_B}{\partial\phi}\left(\frac{(t^*_A-t^*_P)\phi k}{\pi(1-\beta)}+V_{B_i}(t^*_P\bar{y})\right) + p_B\left(\frac{(t^*_A-t^*_P)k}{\pi(1-\beta)} - \frac{\phi k}{\pi(1-\beta)}\cdot\frac{\partial t^*_P}{\partial\phi} + V'_{B_i}(t^*_P\bar{y})\cdot\bar{y}\frac{\partial t^*_P}{\partial\phi}\right)\\
&= \frac{\partial p_B}{\partial\phi}\left(\frac{(t^*_A-t^*_P)\phi k}{\pi(1-\beta)}+V_{B_i}(t^*_P\bar{y})\right) + p_B\left(\frac{(t^*_A-t^*_P)k}{\pi(1-\beta)} - y_{B_i}\cdot\frac{\partial t^*_P}{\partial\phi} + \frac{y_{B_i}}{\bar{y}}\cdot\bar{y}\frac{\partial t^*_P}{\partial\phi}\right)\\
&= \frac{\partial p_B}{\partial\phi}\left(\frac{(t^*_A-t^*_P)\phi k}{\pi(1-\beta)}+V_{B_i}(t^*_P\bar{y})\right) + p_B\left(\frac{(t^*_A-t^*_P)k}{\pi(1-\beta)}\right).
\end{align*}
This is a demonstration of the envelope theorem.
